# How to use request synchronously in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

Here is my very basic script to scrape a given URL and get all the links in it.
I want to print the `links_arr` after the request function is complete. But, here the request callback function is executed and so, I get an empty array printed. How do i do this synchronously? i.e. in the following sequence.

1. URL is requested.
2. Cheerio gets all the links.
3. We loop through all the items, and insert them into the links_arr array.
4. Print the array.

P.S. I know that Node.js meant for asynchronous tasks, but this is the requirement that I need to fulfill. I read that there are things like Promises which can help me in this, but, since I don't have advanced knowledge in Node, I don't know how to implement it. Some help would be much appreciated.
I am using [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library for http requests, [url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) for url parsing, and [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) for html parsing.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = require('url');
var all_links = [];
var processing = [];
var processed = [];
var base_url = "https://www.npmjs.com";
var base_host = "www.npmjs.com";


var analyze_href_sync = function(u){
    console.log("Analysing URL "+u);
    url_obj = url.parse(u);
    url_formatted = url.format(url_obj);
    if (!url_obj.host) {
        //Relative URL
        resolved_url = url.resolve(base_url, url_formatted);
        return resolved_url;
    } else if (url_obj.protocol.startsWith("http")){
        if (url_obj.host == base_host) {
            return url_formatted;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var scrape_all_links_sync = function(u){
    console.log("Scraping all links from URL "+u);
    var links_arr = [];
    request(u, function(err, res, body){
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        links = $('a');
        $(links).each(function(i, link){
            href = $(link).attr('href');
            console.log(href);
            links_arr.push(href);
        });
    });

    console.log(links_arr); //Need to print this, after the above request loopo is complete. i.e. After the array is filled.
}

var store_into_csv_sync = function(u){

}

var insert_into_processing_sync = function(u){

}

var remove_from_processing_sync = function(u){

}

var main = function(u){
    var analyze_url = analyze_href_sync(u);
    if (analyze_url != false) {
        scrape_all_links_sync(analyze_url);
    }
}

main(base_url);
```

The output of the above script is

```
Analysing URL https://www.npmjs.com
Scraping all links from URL https://www.npmjs.com/
[]
...
*All the other links found*
```

Comment: There are many libraries simulating async-await tasks. I've released mine (Awync) few weeks ago. You may want to take a look at it https://github.com/tlghn/awync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `console.log(links_arr);` inside the callback function:

```
var scrape_all_links_sync = function(u){
console.log("Scraping all links from URL "+u);
var links_arr = [];
request(u, function(err, res, body){
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    links = $('a');
    $(links).each(function(i, link){
        href = $(link).attr('href');
        console.log(href);
        links_arr.push(href);
    });
    console.log(links_arr); //Need to print this, after the above request loop is complete. i.e. After the array is filled.
  });
}
```

So just move 1 line up the statement and it will be fine.

In JavaScript we have 3 ways of handling asynchronous code:

1. callbacks
2. promises
3. generator based

So you can choose which one to use and you can also mix them (e.g. depends of the library you use). You may read [more information here](https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/).

Comment: That was way more simple than I thought it would be. Worked.

Comment: I'll edit my answer and add some reference to async callbacks

Comment: Would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(links).each(function(i, link){
            href = $(link).attr('href');
            console.log(href);
            links_arr.push(href);
     if(i==links.length-1)
        console.log(links_arr);  
        });
```